# How to include AAR in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, honeywell

Trying to find out what is wrong with this:

[image]
I'm currently trying to find out why I can't import this AAR (Honeywell)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg8IF.jpg).imgur.com/fh0Va.jpg

Comment: Is there an error or something? Perhaps post that as text here rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Not sure if it's an error, or incompatibility. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rual0tmu34wp56/Honeywell_scanner_android_tool.zip?dl=0

Can't get error messages if next is grayed out.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: seems very simple but it wont open the project using a AAR file.  I also tried to import the AAR file